# How to create an automated object in Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I want to create an automated object that moves to a random location on the screen.
The image is being shown but it is not moving to any location.

After importing pygame, setting up the display and loading the desired image, I defined the following parameters:

```
object_start_x = 200
object_start_y = -600
object_width = 60
object_height = 160
object_speed = 1
```

In the main `game_loop`, using the object() function I had previously defined, I took random integers as the x and y coordinates:

```
gameExit = False

while not gameExit:
    object(object_start_x, object_start_y, object_width, object_height)
    object_start_y += object_speed
        if object_start_y >= 50:
            object_start_y = 50
            random_locationx = random.randint(50, display_width - object_width)
            random_locationy = random.randint(50, display_height - object_height)
```

Then, I tried to change the object's position until it was the same as the random integer generated.

```
            if random_locationx < object_start_x:
                object_start_x - object_speed
                if object_start_x == random_locationx:
                    object_start_x == random_locationx
            elif random_locationx > object_start_x:
                object_start_x + object_speed
                if object_start_x == random_locationx:
                    object_start_x == random_locationx
            elif random_locationx == object_start_x:
                object_start_x == random_locationx
```

I repeated the same for `object_start_y` and `random_locationy` for the y coordinate.
Although the image does appear, the object is not moving.
Any ideas on what I can do to fix this?

Edit: In response to @Sal 's comment, [Pygame moving an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8441432/pygame-moving-an-object) does not address my problem as I want to automate an object randomly, not be able to move it myself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pygame moving an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8441432/pygame-moving-an-object)

Comment: Probably `object(object_start_x, object_start_y, object_width, object_height)` has to be done before the application loop (before `while not gameExit:`). That is a guess.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I tried your suggestion, but it still did not work; the image does not show up now.

Comment: Being rude surely doesn't get you any help. The suggestion is perfectly fine, moving an object on screen is exactly the same process no matter how you get the actual movement value... What do you expect `object_start_x - object_speed` and `object_start_x + object_speed` to do?

Comment: @Roope I was not intending to be rude at all, I was just stating how what they suggested was not what I wanted to do. Perhaps you felt it was rude, but that was not how I meant it to be.

Answer (score 0):

There's not much code here, but there's a few issues, so I'll document those:

The random location is only generated once the object passes 50 pixels in `y`.  Maybe this is by design?

```
if object_start_y >= 50:
   object_start_y = 50
   random_locationx = random.randint(50, display_width - object_width)
   random_locationy = random.randint(50, display_height - object_height)
```

It's not clear to me what the purpose of this code-section is, but it looks like the comparison operator `==` is being used, where the assignment operator `=` is intended.

```
if random_locationx < object_start_x:
    object_start_x - object_speed
    if object_start_x == random_locationx:
        object_start_x == random_locationx    # <-- HERE
```

Furthermore, even if this was an assignment, it's saying the equivalent of `if my_fruit == 'apple', then my_fruit = 'apple'`.  It doesn't achieve a change.

I would pack the "Object" data into a structure.  A python `Rect` object would be best, as it already supports x, y, width, height and comes with a great set of utility functions (for collisions etc.)

```
object_start_x = 200
object_start_y = -600
object_width   = 60
object_height  = 160

my_object_rect  = pygame.Rect( object_start_x, object_start_y, object_width, object_height )
my_object_speed = 1   # in Y

...

while not gameExit:

    # Move the object
    my_object_rect.y += my_object_speed
    if ( my_object_rect.y > 50 ):
        rand_x = random.randint(50, display_width - object_width)
        rand_y = random.randint(50, display_height - object_height)
        my_object_rect.topleft = ( rand_x, rand_y )
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, I wanted the object to be past 50 pixels first. I was considering using `Rect` , however since I am using an image and not a shape I was not too sure how to do this.